# How is SHA unique?

Tags: security, hash, cryptography, sha, crc

I am trying to understand SHA uniqueness in simple terms.
For example let us assume there are only messages with maximum length of 4 bits (binery) in whole world. Number of possible messages with different lengths is

- 2 for single bit length
- 2^2 for double bit length
- 2^3 for 3 bit length
- 2^4 for 4 bit length

that would be 2+4+8+16 = 30 (31 if we consider empty message 2^0 = 1)

Lets us consider SHA3(for example) with output length of 3bits (binery), so maximum possible number of digest are 8.
How can a digest be unique if we need to map 30 messages to 8, or why is it hard to find digest collision for 2 unique messages

Comment: Have you heard the pigeon-hole? Which is highly related to the hash functions and their collision-proof.

Comment: You forgot that 2^0=1, there is also an empty message possible. So it's 31 messages, not 30.

Comment: This question is not really about programming, but I'm not sure that it will be well received at cryptography due to the misconception of SHA3 having a 3 bit output.

Comment: I belive Pigeon-hole proves it otherwise, for above example in my question as per the peigion hole theory there must be a collision after 8 unique digests. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming, but crypto (where a cross-post has been closed as a dupe of [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29650/sha-256-almost-unique))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "SHA uniqueness". An SHA value (any version) is not unique, it cannot be, because it maps an infinite number of inputs (an input of any length) to a finite number of outputs.

A cryptographic hash function has three important properties (which make it a crypto hash, over a regular hash):

- strong collision resistance: it is very difficult (computationally infeasible, ie. "not practically possible") to find two inputs that produce the same output (even if you can choose both)
- weak collision resistance: for a given input, it is computationally infeasible to find another input that gives the same hash value (you can choose one input to match the output of a given input)
- preimage resistance: for a hash value, it's computationally infeasible to find an input that produces that output (it's "one-way")

The only problem in your example is the size. With such small numbers it doesn't  make sense of course. But if the hash value is say 512 bits, it suddenly gets really time consuming and hence practically impossible to brute force.

Comment: @kelalaka Did I say otherwise? :) (Edit: do you mean the phrasing to find THE input? you're actually right - I correct that because that's not a good way to phrase that, thank you)

Comment: Formal definitions are [better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52957495/1820553) by P. Rogaway, wrote here on SO since the accepted answer was wrong and never corrected. Usually, we don't answer non-programming Cryptography questions.

Comment: This answer needs the calculations like [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/64315/18298). As I've noted under the question the OP need to learn about the pigeon-hole principle that you might consider.

Comment: My question is more of how theproperty of strong collision resistance guaranteed? is it only the high output hash length that makes it computationally infeasible to find a collision.

Answer (score 0):

"SHA3 which has digest length of 3bits"

I think this question is based on one bit misunderstanding. SHA-3 is a **family of hashes** that has the same output bit size as SHA-2. SHA-2 has bit sizes 224, 256, 384 or 512 for SHA-224, SHA-256, SHA-384 and SHA-512 respectively.

Of course, SHA-2 already took those identifiers, so SHA-3 will have SHA3-224, SHA3-256, SHA3-384 and SHA3-512. There were some proposals to use a different acronym, but those failed.

Still, SHA-3 hashes have near infinite input, so there will be many hashes that map to the same value. However, since it is not possible reverse any SHA-3 algorithm, it should be impossible to find a collision. That is, unless SHA-3 is broken, as it is not provably secure.

Comment: Of course things will get strange once we get to the SHA-160 family of hashes, but I think we can decide on a new acronym by *then*. Actually I think human kind is by then extinct, but that's another issue.

Comment: I gave SHA with 3 bit output as an example, I think it is not expressed clearly in the question. I will specify the same

Answer (score -1):

Any SHA3 variant will have digests with more than 100 bits. The terminology has probably confused you, because SHA256 has 256 bits, while SHA3 is considered the third generation of SHA algorithms (and does NOT have 3 bits of lenght).

Generally speaking it's not hard to find a hash collision by brute-forcing (alas, it's time-consuming), what is difficult is producing a collision that is also meaningful in its context. For example, assume you have a source file for an important application, that hashes to a digest. If an attacker tried to alter the source file in a way to introduce a vulnerability, while also hashing to the same digest, he'd have to introduce a lot of random gibberish, making the attack obvious.

Comment: It is very misleading to say that it is not hard to find a collision for any proper crypto hash function. It is the very point that it's **really** hard to find one. Not logically complex of course because you "only" have to go through a large number of inputs. But practically impossible, because there are simply too many.

Comment: I made it clear that it's "time-consuming", but the point is that finding a *meaningful* collision is on way another level of "hard".

Comment: No it's not just time consuming. It's practically impossible, because the required amount of time is really very long. For good crypto hashes a collision has never ever been found.

Comment: It depends on the hash complexity, really. The original question started with 3 bits digests, so in its context it makes sense. 
I want to stress that finding a pre-image that makes sense in a given context is much more important and much more difficult, than just finding a random collision.

Comment: As long as you keep stating that it is "not hard" to find a collision in SHA-3 without a major breakthrough, this answer is false, and will stay false. Kudos for spotting the problem in the first section but that second section needs to be replaced.